# Determine a date starting from two integer numbers

Tags: python

Determine a date (as day, month, year) starting from two integer numbers that represent the year and the number of the day in that year.

i'm new to coding and I don't know where to start even.

Comment: the day in that year - you mean 1 <= day <=365 ?

Comment: You haven't provided much information, please elaborate and give an example.

Comment: so if the inputs are year=2004 and days=68 the output should be 8.03.2004

Comment: I think this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-day-number-to-date-in-particular-year/ would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you can use Python datetime module to do what you need:

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.strptime("2004-68", "%Y-%j").strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))
```

Result:

```
08.03.2004
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with creating algorithm in your head, or on paper.
Then you can translate it to python code.

or

you can read documentation about datetime lib in python and try to combine functions to you desired output. https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

For example:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
year = 2004
days = 68
date = datetime(year, 1, 1) + timedelta(days=days-1)
# days-1 is needed because we already start with first day in year
print(date)
# 2004-03-08 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
year=int(input("year="))
days=int(input("number of days="))
day=int
month = days/28 + 1
m = int(month)
if ((year % 400 == 0) or
        (year % 100 != 0) and
        (year % 4 == 0)) :
    day = days % 30
else:
    day = days % 30 + 1

print(day,".", m, ".",year)
```

is this any good? or more preciseley is it corect? like i need this more basic aproach to the problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).